# Number of warnings on node modules, can these be addressed in the latest version of jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

Number of warnings on node modules, can these be addressed in the latest version of jhipster?

```
npm WARN deprecated @types/jest-diff@24.3.0: This is a stub types definition. jest-diff provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated swagger-ui@2.2.10: No longer maintained, please upgrade to swagger-ui@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.5: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

Comment: Not really a question for stackoverflow.com but rather for JHipster project on github. Which version of JHipster are you using? swagger-ui has been upgraded to 3.24.3. For the others, some of these are not direct dependencies but transitive dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) see in package-lock.json or yarn.lock file in your generated project.

Comment: Some of these warnings are due to webpack-visualizer-plugin, I proposed to remove it or to replace it: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11265

Comment: I am using the Latest Version of Jhipster

Comment: Have you upgraded or re-generated your project with JHipster 6.7.1? This is the version that includes my fix in the link above.

Comment: It woked after the upgrade.. thanks